# At what point would giving biased attention, positive or negative, to a candidate, constitute endorsement of or opposition to a candidate?

Tags: non-profit

This question is regarding the Johnson Amendment. Suppose that a 501(c)(3) does not specifically endorse or oppose a candidate, but rather has a biased narrative regarding the candidates. At what point would this reasonably violate the Johnson Amendment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is room for interpretation. The Congressional Research Service issued a [paper](http://www.pgdc.com/pgdc/501c3s-and-campaign-activity-analysis-under-tax-and-campaign-finance-laws) in 2013 which restates what it found the law to be. However, there isn't a corpus of publicly available cases which test the limits (post Citizens United or otherwise). There seems to be a [private letter](http://www.pgdc.com/pgdc/organizations-exempt-status-revoked-political-campaigning) from the IRS (redacted) where such a status was revoked for political involvement.

The CRS analysis article repeats the statutory law which prohibits

> "participating in, or intervening in (including the publishing or
>   distributing of statements), any political campaign on behalf of (or
>   in opposition to) any candidate for public office,"

and then comments that the law "does not further elaborate on the prohibition". Moving on to the regulatory language from Treasury, they observe

> As to what types of activities are prohibited, the regulations add
>   little besides specifying that they include "the publication or
>   distribution of written or printed statements or the making of oral
>   statements on behalf of or in opposition to such a candidate.

which is just a restatement of the unclear statute. They note that

> organizations are allowed to conduct activities that are political in
>   nature but are not related to elections, such as lobbying for or
>   against legislation

and

> may engage in certain election-related activities so long as the
>   activities do not indicate a preference for or against any candidate

but

> Whether such an activity is campaign intervention depends on the facts
>   and circumstances of each case.

For instance, voters guides are supposed to be unbiased, and

> there are numerous ways in which a guide may be biased, and the
>   determination will depend on the facts and circumstances of each case

Issue advocacy is clearly allowed but

> the line between issue advocacy and campaign activity can be difficult
>   to discern.

In some rare instances where all candidates advocate the same position on an issue, issue-advocacy is not a surrogate for candidate advocacy. The report indicates that the IRS has studied the general question, but the IRS reports are no longer available through the IRS, but if [this](http://unclefed.com/Tax-News/2008/2006paci_report_5-30-07.pdf) is the 2006 report, no specific details are revealed (which would lead to discerning the extend to which issue-advocacy can substitute for candidate-advocacy). In short, there is no way to know what is allowed versus prohibited by the IRS.

Comment: The answer needs to bring more of the linked material into it to be a stand alone answer.